# Not able to create Delivery Plans on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am facing this error while creating the Delivery Plan.

> TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation: Hosted Stakeholder License Security Subject. The following permissions are needed to perform this operation: Agile plans..

Answer (score 3):

As it says, your user is assigned a Stakeholder license at the Organization level. You need a paid license to edit delivery plans. Either assign a Basic license or a Visual Studio Subscription to your account or ask your administrator to do that for you.

Comment: thanks! It worked...my admin has changed my license to basic.